# git aws.push returns "error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400"

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have had a working AWS EB environment for many months across a few projects.

Today "git aws.push" stopped working.

There have been a number of updates recently for xcode and os x yosemite but I believe these happened days ago and git aws.push was still working then. It has stopped working across my projects.

The error shown is

> error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400 fatal: The remote end
>   hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have tried an "eb init" which didn't do anything.
I have also tried "git aws.config" which has all the right settings unless my AWS Authenticaiton Keys have changed overnight.

Any help gratefully received on how to fix this.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Yesterday it was working fine and suddenly today it has stopped working.

Comment: what does eb --version yields? if it's anything less than 2.6.3 then you should reinstall the cli from http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743

Comment: Did anyone manage to fix this?  We are getting the same issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this.  Solution is upgrading the EB Command Line tools and resetting all of the places it is referenced. Here's what we did.

1. Install the latest EB Command Line Tools.  This includes updating the bash profile to point to the new instance
2. Go to the application source directory, remove .git/AWSDevTools directory
3. Open `.git/config`, delete the following three sections: alias "aws.elasticbeanstalk", aws "endpoint", alias "aws"
4. Run `eb init` again from the application source directory.
5. Then we got an error saying that we needed to install boto.  So we did `pip install boto`.  (We are using python)

Finally git aws.push worked!!!

Details: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164953&tstart=0

Comment: I got mine working again just installing boto and restarting mac terminal.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you can try:

1. Check your remote URL (i.e. Application and Environment).
2. Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of
   your repo: git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400.
3. Create a new folder, checkout your application and redo *git aws.config*.