# Elastic Beanstalk git aws.push issues

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I've started getting the following error on `git aws.push` when using AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.0 (version which required Ruby):

```
MacBook-Pro:apps-prd katia$ git aws.push
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 126.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 10), reused 4 (delta 1)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578774/git-aws-push-returns-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-400/26812563#26812563) which suggested getting the recent version of EB Command Line tools and resetting all of the places it is referenced.

After getting recent ASW CLI (2.6.4) and reconfiguring I am getting this message on `git aws.push`:

```
MacBook-Pro:apps-prd katia$ git aws.push
Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment eb-prescoapps-php-env...
Environment update initiated successfully.
```

However, it takes around 20-30 minutes (long pose between line 2 and 3) to deploy my application after every commit, whereas before it would take 1-3 minutes depending on a commit.

Is this a standard behaviour? Does the whole applications gets deployed and not just the committed changes? Is there a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I just did an update to EB CLI 2.6.4 and now it's working. It is a little bit slower than the previous version but no more than 2min.

People,
If you don't want to do `eb init` after an upgrade to 2.6.4, you could only update the `.git/config` file with the following

```
[alias "aws.elasticbeanstalk"]
    remote = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push --remote-url
    push = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
    config = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
    createapplicationversion = !.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.createapplicationversion
[aws "endpoint"]
    us-east-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2 = git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2 = git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1 = git.elasticbeanstalk.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
[alias "aws"]
    push = !git aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
    config = !git aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
    createapplicationversion = !git aws.elasticbeanstalk.createapplicationversion
```

Maybe AWS Support can confirm the above.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues, I highly recommend that you upgrade to the [EB CLI 3.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-set-up.html). It fixes a lot of issues that the previous version has and is a better experience.

You can see what version you are running by the following:

```
eb --version
```